# Check if user is logged in on Facebook using graph API on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook

I am making a feedback form using the Facebook graph API for the iPhone. When the user gives feedback, we want to check if the user is already logged in on Facebook or not.

Please Any one can do help.

```
- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender {
    // This button pressed method check that user is already login or not 
}
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: where are you initializing your facebook?

Answer (score 0):

You can Check fb Session by writting  Following code in Appdelegate.m File :

```
 - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        /*
         Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
         */
        [self performSelector:@selector(checkingFBsession) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];

    }

-(void)checkingFBsession
{
   self.successfb= [[self facebook] isSessionValid];
    NSString *str = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"access_token"];
    [str retain];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
    if (self.successfb || str) {
        NSLog(@"session is valid !");

        accessToken=self.facebook.accessToken;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

        accessToken = nil;
        accessToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"access_token"];
      [accessToken retain];
        NSLog(@"at%@",accessToken);
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"];
        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setDelegate:self];
        [request addPostValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"access_token"] forKey:@"access_token"];

        //    [request addPostValue:@"123456" forKey:@"telephone"];
        [request startAsynchronous];
        }


}
```

Comment: Try to check here may b You will Find Solution : https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample/Hackbook